# Implementing Admob Native ads in Flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, native-ads, google-native-ads

What is the best and easiest way to implement **Admob Native Ads** in Flutter? Is that within the scope of the 'Google Mobile Ads SDK' package or I need to use another package?

Answer (score 0):

**Rifat**, I've successfully implemented the AdMob support in my Flutter app recently.

To integrate AdMob into your Flutter app

- use the [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads) package

Also, this codelab will be very helpful

- [Adding an AdMob banner and native inline ads to a Flutter app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter#0)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the google_mobile_ads package to your pubspec.yaml file. An example from the documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads/example

I also found a post related to your topic. I think the steps here will work.
https://itnext.io/flutter-native-ads-92d802fbd927

I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.